# Flutter observe table on Postgresql database and send notification

Tags: postgresql, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

after some days of thinking about my problem I came to an end and need some advice from experts. I am currently building a flutter app which should run on both desktop and mobile. Now I want to implement a background service which runs even if the app is not running. This service should observe a Table on a postgresql Database and everytime a new entry comes in a notification should be send to the user on the phone.

My question is now if anybody has experience in this section and maybe an advice how I could go on and solve this problem.

I already read something about creating trigger in the database but I could not figure out how to send the data/notification to the user by just using a trigger. Maybe if someone has an example or a small description how he/she solved this problem.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.